# How to paste event from a Listener to an InteractiveViewer as a child in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a Listener Widget which listens for any pointer event with an InteractiveViewer widget as child. The Listener events should only call a callback function and not block any events from the InteractiveViewer.

I've already tried it with a GestureDetector, but I need to to listen for all events and this means to define all possible gestures in the GestureDetector is to much effort

The onInteractionUpdate gets never called. How can I call and keep the Listener Widget?

```dart
Listener(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        onPointerDown: (event) => callBack_1(),
        onPointerCancel: (event) => callBack_2(),
        onPointerUp: (event) => callBack_2(),
        child: InteractiveViewer(
          onInteractionUpdate: (details) => print("I get never called :("),
          child: ...
```

Comment: and your question is? you are calling now two methods, what's wrong with them?

Comment: the question is 1. "How can I call the `onInteractionUpdate`, 2. still get the Events from the Listener 3. but keep it out of the GestureArena"?

Comment: try `GestureBinding.pointerRouter` and its `addGlobalRoute` method

Comment: `RawGestureDetector` with `HitTestBehavior.deferToChild` works in my case..

Comment: and how do you want to get all the pointer events with that?

Comment: I only need to intercept `onTapCancel`, `onTapUp` and `onTapDown`. I'm not handling this events there. They only call the callback which sets with setState a flag in another Widget. The rest (panning, dragging, etc) should still 'bubble' to the InteractiveViewer